# Segmentation Fault - How do I figure out what is wrong with my code? - C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm extremely new to programming and am trying to work out a program. However, I'm not getting any useful errors. The program compiles, but I get a "segmentation fault" message halfway through execution. In this program I'm asking for a month and day as input,then call a function (my plan is to pass the date string, and the address of a tempmonth array and a tempday integer) that separates the date into the month and the day and stores them in the address. Then print the data in main. I've been trying for hours to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the pointers and addresses...but I just can't figure it out. Here's the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void separate(char*,char*,int*);

int main()

{    

        char date[12];
        printf("Enter a month and a day: ");
        fgets(date,12,stdin);

        char tempmonth[10];
        int tempday;
        separate(date,&*tempmonth,&tempday);

        printf("month is %s and day is %d",tempmonth,tempday);

        return 0;
}

void separate(char*date,char*tempmonth, int*tempday)

{

        sscanf(date,"%s %d",*tempmonth,*tempday);
}
```

(For some reason the * won't print by char*date and char*tempmonth - it's supposed to be there.)
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Narrow the problem down. Where exactly does the error happen?

Comment: `How to figure out ?` - try to use some debugger like `gdb`.

Comment: Also, read the manual, *carefully*, of *every single* library function that you use. And enable compiler warnings. (It's not so much that the error isn't pretty obvious, but it's more that you learn the mechanics of looking things up and narrowing things down, without which you'll never ever get any program working.)

Comment: I get the input date just fine. But get segmentation error right after.

Comment: What type of arguments do `scanf` (and family) expects? What does the dereference `*` operator do? What types are the arguments to the `separate`  function?

Comment: I have A First Book of Ansi C which I've spent hours rifling through trying to figure out what was wrong...also spent hours googling...and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Also note that the address-of operator `&` and the dereference operator `*` are each others opposites, so when doing e.g. `&*tempmonth` the two operators cancel each other out, and it's the same as just `tempmonth`.

Comment: If you want to reply to a specific user, mention him like this: @TaylorAsh. If you want to add information to your post, use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36397395/edit).

Comment: Note: stop counting beans.  Unless you are on a RAM-poor embedded environment, declare text buffers as [256].  No 12,10 rubbish - 256, no smaller.

Comment: Why do you use `*tempmonth` and `*tempday` in `sscanf`? The `sscanf` function needs the addresses to put the data into, not the values those addresses currently contain.

Comment: *Write down* answers to Joachim's questions, in full, like this: "sscanf with the format I have used expects arguments of type ___ and ___" etc.

Comment: In case of a segmentation fault, always put array-access operations at the top of your suspect list. `printf` argument type vs argument list could be the second most suspecious category, but I guess it's more of a matter of opinion.

Comment: An extra star seems to have crept in: separate(date,&*tempmonth,&tempday);

Comment: I got the sscanf to work just fine...but in main. Here, I need to use it in the function - so I know the issue is something with the passing address or pointers or something along those lines...but have no clue past that. The types of arguments to the separate function - 1. string 2. address of array 3. address of integer. * as I've learned is a pointer, and can also be used for a string - ex: char string[] to char*string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler might have shown you warnings like this:

> `‘%s’` expects argument of type `‘char*’`, but argument `3` has type
>   `‘int’`
>
> `‘%d’` expects argument of type `‘int*’`, but argument `4` has type
>   `‘int’`

---

As `sscanf` takes a *pointer* as an argument where you have passed a `int` that is why its creating a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. You are accessing an address `*tempmonth` (the value stored in `tempmonth`), which might be *inaccessible* by your program. Inaccessible means that the address doesn't belong to the memory provided to your program by the OS or the process doesn't have required permissions to access it.

Change the line

```
sscanf(date,"%s %d",*tempmonth,*tempday);
```

to

```
sscanf(date,"%s %d",tempmonth,tempday);
```

as `tempmonth` and `tempday` are already pointers.

Also in calling `separate(date,&*tempmonth,&tempday);` writing `&*tempmonth` is equvalent to  `tempmonth` because you are referencing and dereferencing the same pointer; both will cancel out.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you wrote and got the program to work. The reason I had put &*tempmonth - was because I was trying to pass the address to the function, and when I only had &tempmonth, it was giving me an error...so I randomly tried adding the * and the error went away. I didn't realize those canceled each other out...

Answer (score 1):

> separate(date,&*tempmonth,&tempday);

`&*tempmonth` is the address of the object pointed by tempmonth... which is tempmonth, so `&*tempmonth` --> `tempmonth`

> sscanf(date,"%s %d",*tempmonth,*tempday);

`sscanf` needs addresses of where to store the data. As `tempmonth` is a pointer to the first character of your chain, `*tempmonth` IS the first character of your chain. Same with `tempday`, it is already the address, meaning that `*tempday` is the actual value. Therefore change this line to:

```
sscanf(date,"%s %d",tempmonth, tempday);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should narrow the problem: what line is causing the segmentation fault?
To answer this, use experience to guess or you could use a debugger like gdb, you can insert a break point(s) in a line, when the program runs and reaches this line it will stop and you will have control over execution, you will be able to execute your program step by step.
In your example, try inserting a breakpoint in your function separate.
Now you will see that the Segmentation Fault happens when your os executes sscanf, search for the prototype of sscanf, compare the type of parameters you are passing with what sscanf is expecting and you will solve your problem.
`

Comment: I didn't even know there was an option to execute programs step by step. That's how new I am. I tried googling how to add breakpoints but am just getting confusing information. Is there just a simple way to do it?